# Consider the topological space $X$ consisting of two concentric circles. Is $X$ Hausdorff? Is $X$ first countable?

Tags: general-topology

Let Consider the topological space $X$ consisting of two concentric circles
namely, inner circle is $C_{1}$ and outer circle is $C_{2}$. We put a topology on $X$
with the subbasis the collection of all single point set in $C_{2}$ together with
all open arcs on $C_{1}$ with the radial projection of all but the midpoints on
$C_{2} .$ I have questions that: Is $X$ Hausdorff? Is $X$ first countable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is Hausdorff because the corrsponding points (twins) in the two circles are separated by their basic neighbourhoods (the inner has the open segment on the inside plus an open segment on the outside minus its "twin", the twin has just its singleton as a disjoint open set from that). In other cases (non-twins) just take small enough double segments for points on the inner circle and singletons for outer circle points.

The standard basic elements show that $X$ is also first countable (just take double segments of inner lengths $\frac{1}{n}$ for inner points, singletons for outer points).

It's not separable (thus also not second countable ) as the outer circle as a subspace is open and discrete and uncountable. Any dense subset of $X$ must contain all points of the outer circle.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, the space is not 1st countable because the
outer circle is an uncountable discrete subspace.
Yes it is Hausdorff which is easy to prove.

Comment: You mean second countable, I think?